# Does SnappyData in HDFS read write mode support a Primary key in tables?

Tags: snappydata

I was reading about the HDFS persistence mode in SnappyData and it was confusing in the documentation.

Can one create tables with primary keys that read/write to HDFS?

http://rowstore.docs.snappydata.io/docs/disk_storage/persist-hdfs-topics.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create HDFS read/write tables with PRIMARY KEY defined. It's just that the HDFS read/write tables that use eviction criteria cannot have foreign key constraints, because the table data needed to enforce such constraints would require scanning persisted HDFS data.